# API tkinter python entry

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I have a problem with the entry. I want the user to write in any city they want in the
API link. I get that i cant convert to a str. So when ever the user choose to enter a city he can just click on the button forecast after he entered the city in the Entry and the weather will be printed:

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import json

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.root = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.v = StringVar()
        self.e = Entry(self, textvariable=self.v)
        self.e.pack(side="left")

        self.v.set("Enter City")
        self.s = self.v.get()
        self.e.focus_set()


        self.butn = Button(self)
        self.butn["text"] = "Forecast"
        self.butn["command"] = self.make_request
        self.butn.pack(side="left")

        self.QUIT = Button(self, text="QUIT", command=self.root.destroy)
        self.QUIT.pack(side="right")


    def make_request(self):
        r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/ab78bcbaca641959/forecast/q/Sweden/" + ???? + ".json")
        data = r.json()
        for day in data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:
            print (day['date']['weekday'] + ":")
            print ("Conditions: ", day['conditions'])
            print ("High: ", day['high']['celsius'] + "C", "Low: ", day['low']['celsius'] + "C", '\n')
        return data






rot = Tk()
rot.geometry("900x650+200+50")
rot.title("The Trip")

app = Application(master=rot)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self.v.get()` in place of `????` and it works

```
r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/ab78bcbaca641959/forecast/q/Sweden/" + self.v.get() + ".json")
```

By the way: you don't need `self.s = self.v.get()` anymore.